# Predicting a point in Python 2D Space

Tags: python, vector, 2d, prediction

I am making a game in python that currently has two "Agents" one that DOESN'T MOVE and shoots, and the other that moves and gets shot at. Unfortunately I can't post pictures yet. Imagine two triangle shaped agents, with red circles for bullets. We use vector2D's (our lecturer's class) to represent the agents and I am using it for  the bullets too.

Currently, my  code produces the bullets from the shooter, but aims at the evading agent's CURRENT position upon firing - rather than where it will be. Not only that, it seems to produce bullets from the opposite side as well.

Apologies in advance for the bad code - here is currently what my 'shoot' function does.

```
def shoot(self, target_pos, target):
    ''' move towards target position '''

    toTarget = (self.targetpos - self.pos)
    relativeHeading = self.heading.dot(self.targetheading)

    lookAheadTime = toTarget.length() / (self.max_speed + 40)


    lookAheadTime += (1 - self.heading.dot(self.targetpos))* - self.max_turnrate
    lookAheadPos = self.targetpos + self.targetvelocity * lookAheadTime
    desired_vel = (lookAheadPos - self.pos).normalise() * self.max_speed
    print(lookAheadPos)
    trueVel = desired_vel - self.vel

    if (toTarget.dot(self.heading)>0) and (relativeHeading < 0.95):
        return trueVel
    return trueVel
```

This is used in 'calculate' which is passed in to 'update' (which is done each update step for the world space).

```
 def calculate(self, delta, targetpos):
    # reset the steering force
    force = self.shoot(self.targetpos, self.world.agents[0])
    return force
```

Here is what happens to it in update. Currently the bullets do some weird jittering as well.

```
 bulPos = (self.pos - self.targetpos).length()
    self.distCovered += 1

    if self.distCovered > 250:
       self.world.bullets.remove(self)
       self.world.bulletsize -= 1

    toTarget = self.targetpos - self.pos
    if toTarget.lengthSq() <= self.targetradius:
        self.explode()
```

In the agent class, bullets are appended in the agent's update.

```
  if self.world.bulletsize <= 10: 
        self.world.bullets.append(Bullet(self.world.hunter.pos.x, self.world.hunter.pos.y, self.world.agents[0], self.world))
        self.world.bulletsize += 1
```

Comment: What does `self.targetpos` refer to, shouldn't that be `target_pos`?

Comment: Yeah it should be - self.targetpos is passed target_pos in init so its the same thing (just bad code)

Comment: If it's not too much to fit, editing your answer to add some of the other code would help people understand how the whole thing works.

Comment: There we go, hope that helps